# How to test performance in junit test?

Tags: performance, testing, load, system

I have an application that have different versions. I would like to check performance from version to version. But I have very limited resources on server - sometimes processor is loaded by other applications, sometimes not. 
So checking time of execution cannot produce correct result.
May exists another way? E.g. count number of processor cycles or take in account system loading, etc. ?
Thanks.